# Sonarqube rule for JUnit @Ignore

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, sonarqube

I'm concerned about some developers who usually ignore failing tests with @Ignore to bypass SonarQube static verification.

For that I'm looking a rule that creates issues.

Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

I'm using SonarQube 5.4 and JUnit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be a rule for this: `Rule S1607: Tests should not be ignored` (old)

However this rule was updated and now actually allows ignored Tests, if appropriatly commented: [`Rule S1607: JUnit4 @Ignored and JUnit5 @Disabled annotations should be used to disable tests and should provide a rationale` (new)](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?languages=java&open=java%3AS1607&q=Tests+ignore)

Comment: The link no longer points to any rule. Has the rule been removed?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers Thanks for the notice, the rule was updated. I fixed the link and mentioned the change.